# Find string in SQL column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have the next code(found here at stack overflow):

```
 string [] arr = {"One","Two","Three"};
   var target = "One";
   var results = Array.FindAll(arr, s => s.Equals(target));
```

This code good for search string on array... i need to find string in sql column.

Let's say i have table ("Names"), and i want to find "Jhon".. how can i do that?

- I don't need connectionstring or the whole method, that's i know to do, but i can't think on method to search specific string at sql table.
- Will be great to see version of search: "Jh" and it will find "Jhon" if is there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to avoid sql injection if target is user provided

```
string connectionString= ...
string target="jh";

using (var conn=new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
conn.Open();
  using (var cmd=conn.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText="select Name from Names where Name like '%'+@value+'%'";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value",target);

    using (var reader=cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (reader.Read()) { 
            Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
        }
    }

  }
}
```

- Use `like '%'+@value+'%'` for contains
- Use `like @value+'%'` for starts with
- Use `like '%'+@value` for ends with

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT NAME
FROM NAMES
WHERE NAME='Jhon'
```

Is this what you're looking for?

If only a part of it needs to match:

```
...
WHERE NAME LIKE 'Jh%'
```

[LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Comment: Probably a `like` clause would be more useful - `SELECT Name FROM Names WHERE Name like '%Jhon%'`